# Ember 2, Simply modals as components, not controllers

Tags: javascript, ember.js, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, ember-cli

I searched but nothing made me happy.

I found this: http://ember.guru/2014/master-your-modals-in-ember-js

But he's using controller. I need to use components.

**How can I use this code for component?**

*app/routes/application.js*

```
showModal(name, model) {
  console.log('showModal() in application.js called!');
  this.render('components/' + name, {
    into: 'application',
    outlet: 'modal',
    model: model
  });
},

removeModal() {
  console.log('removeModal() in application.js called!');
  this.disconnectOutlet({
    outlet: 'modal',
    parentView: 'application'
  });
}
```

`this.render` just renders, of course, the .hbs of my component. The code (like `didInsertElement`) of that component is not executed.

Maybe with a **fake template** in templates folder? **But how**?

Comment: What version of Ember are you using? This doesn't look up to date.

Comment: Im using 2.13...

Comment: You are following an article from 2014 - it's outdated

Comment: OK. Can you answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using `render` is discouraged and instead use [ember-elsewhere addon](https://github.com/ef4/ember-elsewhere).

https://www.emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x/#toc_rendering-into-a-render-helper-that-resolves-to-an-outlet

Comment: Can you answer my question about how to render dinamically a component? I think ember-elsewhere is too much heavy for my needs...